# Select performance problems with conditional index vs non-conditional on large volume table

Tags: oracle, index, performance, oracle-11g, query-performance

We are trying to change some indexes on a large-volume table to be conditional indexes (function-based indexes) to reduce how much space is being used for indexes against this table.  When testing the performance insert and update times are very minorly affected and easily acceptable.  Reads where most of the filtering down is done on the columns in the index show almost no change from non-conditional to conditional index.

However, reads where filtering by the columns in the index still leaves a large number of remaining records and a significant amount of filtering after that takes place using columns not in the index see a significant difference.  After adding some data, deleting and re-creating the indexes, and gathering statistics the first read showed similar times between our baseline (index is not conditional) and the conditional index.  Subsequent reads using the same query improved greatly for the baseline and did not improve with the conditional index use.  I suspect the baseline queries are taking advantage of caching that the conditional index is not.

Has anyone encountered similar performance problems using conditional indexes on Oracle?  Any advice how we can determine the exact cause and hopefully avoid this slower performance with the conditional indexes?

We are using Oracle 11g, running the queries in SQL plus or from an application using OleDB doesn't make a difference.  We have verified the explain plan for both cases shows the same query plan, only the costs change.

I'll be changing the table and field names here but the structure is the same:

Baseline Index:

```
CREATE INDEX IEMP_CMPHIRDEP ON EMPLOYEE (COMPANY, HIRE_DATE, DEPT_ID, EMP_ID);
```

Function-based version (In this case a new column "ARCHIVED" is added to the EMPLOYEE table and the function-based index is made conditional on this column being 'N'.  If it is any other value the row will not be included in the index.):

```
CREATE INDEX IEMP_CMPHIRDEP ON EMPLOYEE (
    CASE WHEN ARCHIVED = 'N' THEN COMPANY END,
    CASE WHEN ARCHIVED = 'N' THEN HIRE_DATE END,
    CASE WHEN ARCHIVED = 'N' THEN DEPT_ID END,
    CASE WHEN ARCHIVED = 'N' THEN EMP_ID END
);
```

Query which illustrates the performance issue (the query used for the baseline environment is identical to this except that it does not have the CASE statements which are needed to hit the index when using the function-based index):

```
SELECT /*+ ORDERED  index(EMPLOYEE IEMP_CMPHIRDEP)*/ * 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE ((CASE WHEN ARCHIVED = 'N' THEN EMPLOYEE.COMPANY END = 'A') 
        AND (CASE WHEN ARCHIVED = 'N' THEN EMPLOYEE.HIRE_DATE END = '09-Sep-2015')
        AND (CASE WHEN ARCHIVED = 'N' THEN EMPLOYEE.DEPT_ID END = 'SALES')  
        AND (EMPLOYEE.LOCATION >= 10000 AND EMPLOYEE.LOCATION <= 10000) 
        AND (EMPLOYEE.PAY >= 30 AND EMPLOYEE.PAY <= 32) 
        AND (EMPLOYEE.SKILLS IN ('A','B','C','D','E'))) 
ORDER BY EMPLOYEE.DEPT_ID,EMPLOYEE.ORG_CODE,EMPLOYEE.EMP_ID;
```

In this case filtering by COMPANY, HIRE_DATE, and DEPT_ID, which are in the index only narrows down to ~2 million rows.  The filtering on LOCATION and PAY narrows the results down to 965 rows.  The EMPLOYEE table has over 62 million rows.

Here are the times (in milliseconds) for 10 consecutive reads using that query in the baseline environment:

1. 71619.51
2. 29827.58
3. 30306.79
4. 30365.6
5. 29871.75
6. 29863.03
7. 30345.64
8. 30378.42
9. 29860.57
10. 29776.82

Here are the times (in milliseconds) for 10 consecutive reads in the conditional index environment.  All data in the EMPLOYEE table is identical except for the added ARCHIVED column:

1. 43797.05
2. 43744.57
3. 43562.32
4. 43738.16
5. 43700.51
6. 43759.54
7. 43643.28
8. 43814.34
9. 43607.4
10. 43797.52

Edit 1:
The explain plans I ran before in SQL Developer showed no difference other than cost but this morning we ran the queries in SQLplus (using select count(1) instead of selecting all of the columns) and our DBA took the explain plans for each (I'm the developer working on this project). Something we noticed was that the Rows shown for the index range scan had a big difference between the two.

Baseline:

```
Plan hash value: 68573393
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name                 | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                      |     1 |    43 |    61   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE              |                      |     1 |    43 |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| EMPLOYEE             |     1 |    43 |    61   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IEMP_CMPHIRDEP       |    67 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Function based:

```
Plan hash value: 68573393
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name                 | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                      |     1 |    20 |  1238   (1)| 00:00:15 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE              |                      |     1 |    20 |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| EMPLOYEE             |     1 |    20 |  1238   (1)| 00:00:15 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IEMP_CMPHIRDEP       |  1433 |       |   544   (1)| 00:00:07 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What is the exec plan? Index range scan or fast full scan? Do you have a license for real time SQL monitoring? Did you try to execute the query with gather_stats hint?

Comment: Index range scan, table access by index rowid, filter, then sort.  I'm not sure about the real time monitoring, I'll have to ask.  I haven't tried executing with that hint but we did rebuild the index and gather statistics in each environment before running the queries.

Comment: What percentage of the table includes rows with an archived value of N?

Comment: Why do you think a conditional index will help? A simple index you have can help too. Please treat dates as dates do not force implicit conversion, Oracle avoids using index in that case. what is the performance of this sql (remove quotes) .  "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE (COMPANY = 'A' AND HIRE_DATE = to_date('09-Sep-2015','dd-mon-yyyy') AND DEPT_ID = 'SALES' AND PAY in (30,31,32) AND SKILLS IN ('A','B','C','D','E')) ORDER BY DEPT_ID,ORG_CODE,EMP_ID"
?

Comment: @LeighRiffel 9.3%

Comment: @Raj We are implementing a conditional index to reduce the size of the indexes, we have a lot of indexes on this table that only need to deal with a small subset of the actual rows in the table.  The same query is being run in the baseline environment and with the conditional index with much worse performance using the conditional index.  The actual timings I posted come from running the query in our app which is using bound variables through OleDB but as I mentioned above we ran in SQLplus as well to rule out OleDB as a possible issue and saw the same behavior.

Comment: If your query is showing almost consistent timing (about 43sec) for conditional index, I suspect it is probably not using the index as expected. So, you have to decide if query performance is important to you or index size. It will be hard (time consuming) to balance both. 72-75m rows isn't much. Perhaps you should create a FBI on just archived and company columns and see if other columns are necessary. If you don't want to write complicated conditions in index and match them in where clause, consider virtual columns and index those instead, it will be easier to implement and write.

Comment: Try to execute the query with gather_stats hint and then use dbms_xplan to show execution plan. This might give you some numbers describing how your query is evaluated in reality.

Comment: Your explain plans indicate Oracle thinks that 67 rows would be retrieved with your baseline index, and 1,433 rows would be retrieved with the function-based index.  So the optimizer proceeds with that assumption.  If it is accurate, then the function-based index isn't very selective, and you will be reading a lot more index data with it.  So do you want less index space or faster queries?

Comment: @MarkStewart I guess I don't understand why Oracle thinks it would be different at all.  We are running these on the same hardware, one schema is an exact duplicate of the other except for the index (function-based or not) and the addition of the archive column to the table.  (Only one schema is queried at a time)  Since the table holds the same data I'd expect Oracle to predict the same amount of rows.  For this query 965 rows are returned (same for both baseline and function-based).

Comment: Oracle thinks it is different because you have two different indexes.  If you want the gory details, you would need to enable tracing of the optimizer, run the query, disable tracing; for both scenarios.

`alter session set events '10053 trace name context forever, level 1';`

turns it on and 

`alter session set events '10053 trace name context off';`

turns it off.  The trace goes to a log file, and produces thousands of lines of output that you would need a book to explain what it means.  (I have that book at home)  :)

Comment: Update: We did run the queries with the gather_plan_statistics hint but the resulting explain plans didn't change from the plans I posted above.

Answer (score 3):

All the comments above are appropriate.

If you provide the details on the data types and any not null constraints of the columns in question, then we can better determine whether your function-based approach is appropriate.  I would also gather statistics on the indexes and look at the unique values, etc.  You can compress your baseline index too, if say you have very few unique values for company and hire date, you can compress by two levels.  In fact, you can do the following to see if index compression will help:

```
analyze index IEMP_CMPHIRDEP validate structure;
```

Then query the view index_stats:

```
SYS@instance> select OPT_CMPR_COUNT, OPT_CMPR_PCTSAVE from index_stats;

OPT_CMPR_COUNT OPT_CMPR_PCTSAVE
-------------- ----------------
             3               28
```

In the above example, compressing the index at level 3 would save 28% space.  So if it is a good amount, you would

```
alter index IEMP_CMPHIRDEP rebuild compress 3;
```

Comment: I had a conversation with our DBA about compression, the concern for that path is insert and update performance.  I used EMPLOYEE as I can't reveal our actual schema names but this table has records created and updated in high volumes and it's critical for our application that insert and update times don't increase greatly.  As it was explained to me updating a row with compression in place would require uncompressing, updating the values, then recompressing right?  I'll try to get the data types and not null constraints for you later today.

Comment: The way index compression works does not have much CPU overhead; to oversimplify, if you have 5 unique companies, then the index will have just five company names in the index, instead of a company name entry for each index entry.  But only way to know is to benchmark, as you already have done for the function-based index.  I predict little overhead and big space savings, and since the index will be smaller (well if the analyze index says it would), then you will have fewer physical/logical reads on the index.

Comment: I looked at your explain plans and added a comment to the original question; the data types and constraints are not terribly important after looking at them.  **Index** compression has low overhead; **data** compression does have more of an impact (and requires additional licensing fees).